# create separate i18next without use I18nextProvider

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next, micro-frontend

I've a shell and a microfront project that both use `react-i18next` to manage the languages but I would like that each project control his own `i18next` instance. Is there any way to do it without wrapping my microfront on shell with `I18nextProvider` and providing a new instance?

I've created this [POC](https://github.com/Evando16/mf-i18n-poc/tree/poc-without-provider) that you can simulate the problem just starting and oppening the shell and changing the language, you will see that the keys from the microfront override the shell translation keys.

I would like to have each project working separatally and independent from each other in terms of i18next. Is that possible?

Thx in advance

Comment: btw I would not like to use `I18nextProvider` because with it I need to load the microfront translation key from my shell project

Answer (score 1):

***Answering my own question in order to help someone in the future***

If this help someone, I've manage to solve the problem removing the `react-i18next` from the sharable config of my Module Federation microfront.

**This is will be a problem of downloading the lib twice?**
Yes, but it was the only way that I've found separate the react-i18next instance. If anyone find a different way, pls post here. thx

Answer (score 0):

One of the following solutions might work for you:

**Solution 1:**

You can create additional instances using the [createInstance](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#createinstance) function.

```
i18next.createInstance(options, callback)
```

**Solution 2:**

**Overriding the i18next instance** might serve your purpose.

```
// passing in an i18n instance
// use only if you do not like the default instance
// set by i18next.use(initReactI18next) or the I18nextProvider
import i18n from './i18n';
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation('ns1', { i18n });
```

Read more [here](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#overriding-the-i18next-instance)

**Solution 3:**

Probably, you need to use **I18nextProvider**

```
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from './i18n';
import App from './App';

<I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
  <App />
</I18nextProvider>
```

[when to use I18nextProvider?](https://react.i18next.com/latest/i18nextprovider#when-to-use)